# Kotlin. What is the best way to replace element in immutable list?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, collections, kotlin-extension

What is the best way to update specific item in immutable list. For example I have list of `Item`. And I have several ways to update list:

1.

```
  fun List<Item>.getList(newItem: Item): List<Item> {
        val items = this.toMutableList()
        val index = items.indexOf(newItem)
        if (index  != -1) {
            items[index ] = newItem
        }
        return items 
    }
```

2. 

```
fun List<Item>.getList(newItem: Card): List<Item> {
        return this.map { item ->
            if (item.id == newItem.id) newItem else item
        }
    }
```

The second option looks more concise and I like it more. However, in the second option, we will go through each element in the list, which is bad for me, because the list can contain many elements.

Please, is there a better way to fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options - you're already doing the *"make a mutable copy and update it"* approach, and the *"make a copy by mapping each item and changing what you need"* one.

Another typical approach is to kinda go half-and-half, copying the parts you need, and inserting the bits you want to change. You could do this by, for example, slicing the list around the element you want to change, and building your final list from those parts:

```
fun List<Item>.update(item: Item): List<Item> {
    val itemIndex = indexOf(item)
    return if (itemIndex == -1) this.toList()
    else slice(0 until itemIndex) + item + slice(itemIndex+1 until size)
}
```

This way you get to take advantage of any efficiency from the underlying list copy methods, versus `map` which has to "transform" each item even if it ends up passing through the original.

---

But as always, it's best to benchmark to see how well these approaches actually perform! [Here's a playground example](https://pl.kotl.in/a-RP9Up0c) - definitely not the best place to do benchmarking, but it can be instructive as a general ballpark if you run things a few times:

```
Mapping all elements: 2500 ms
Slicing: 1491 ms
Copy and update index: 611 ms
```

Broadly speaking, mapping takes 60-100% more time than the slice-and-combine approach. And slicing takes 2-3x longer than just a straight mutable copy and update.

Considering what you actually need to do here (get a copy of the list and change (up to) one thing) the last approach seems like the best fit! The others have their benefits depending on how you want to manipulate the list to produce the end result, but since you're barely doing anything here, they just add unnecessary overhead. And of course it depends on your use-case - the slicing approach for example uses more intermediate lists than the mapping approach, and that might be a concern in addition to raw speed.

---

If the verbosity in your first example bothers you, you could always write it like:

```
fun List<Item>.getList(newItem: Item): List<Item> =
    this.toMutableList().apply {
        val index = indexOf(newItem)
        if (index != -1) set(index, newItem)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The second one looks ever so slightly better for performance, but they are both `O(n)`, so it's not a big difference, and hardly worth worrying about. I would go for the second one because it's easier to read.

The first one iterates the list up to 2 times, but the second iteration breaks early once it finds the item. (The first iteration is to copy the list, but it is possibly optimized by the JVM to do a fast array copy under the hood.)

The second one iterates the list a single time, but it does have to do the ID comparison for each item in the list.

Side note: "immutable" is not really the right term for a `List`. They are called "read-only" Lists because the interface does not guarantee immutability. For example:

```
private val mutableList = mutableListOf<Int>()

val readOnlyList: List<Int> get() = mutableList
```

To an outside class, this List is read-only, but not immutable. Its contents might be getting changed internally in the class that owns the list. That would be kind of a fragile design, but it's possible. There are situations where you might want to use a MutableList for performance reasons and pass it to other functions that only expect a read-only List. As long as you don't mutate it while it is in use by that other class, it would be OK.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Perhaps there is a better solution than the options I suggested?

Comment: Not that I know of. I guess you could change your first approach to manually iterate, but that doesn't really change the behavior, and it would be more verbose.

Comment: [Someone opened a feature request for a dedicated function.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25617) Not getting much attention.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could try is, as apparently each item has an `id` field that you are using to identify the item, to create a map from it, perform all your replacements on that map, and convert it back into a list. This is only useful if you can batch all the replacements you need to do, though. It will probably also change the order of the items in the list.

```
fun List<Item>.getList(newItem: Item) =
    associateBy(Item::id)
        .also { map ->
            map[newItem.id] = newItem
        }
        .values
```

And then there’s also the possibility to convert your list into a `Sequence`: this way it will be lazily evaluated; every replacement you add with `.map` will create a new `Sequence` that refers to the old one plus your new mapping, and none of it will be evaluated until you run an operation that actually has to read the whole thing, like `toList()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: if the list is truly immutable and not only read-only; or if its contents could change and you would like to see these changes in the resulting list, then you can also wrap the original list into another one. This is fairly easy to do in Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(
        Item(1, "1-orig"),
        Item(2, "2-orig"),
        Item(3, "3-orig"),
    )
    val list2 = list.getList(Item(2, "2-new"))

    println(list2)
}

fun List<Item>.getList(newItem: Item): List<Item> {
    val found = indexOfFirst { it.id == newItem.id }
    if (found == -1) return this
    return object : AbstractList<Item>() {
        override val size = this@getList.size
        override fun get(index: Int) = if (index == found) newItem else this@getList[index]
    }
}

data class Item(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

This is very good for the performance if you don't plan to repeatedly modify resulting lists with further changes. It is `O(1)` to replace an item and it almost doesn't use any additional memory. However, if you plan to invoke `getList()` repeatedly on a resulting list, each time creating a new one, that would create a chain of lists, slowing down access to the data and preventing garbage collector to clean up replaced items (if you don't use the original list anymore). You can partially optimize this by detecting you invoke `getItem()` on your specific implementation, but even better, you can use already existing libraries that does this.

This pattern is called a [persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) and it is provided by the library [kotlinx.collections.immutable](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable). You can use it like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = persistentListOf(
        Item(1, "1-orig"),
        Item(2, "2-orig"),
        Item(3, "3-orig"),
    )
    val list2 = list.set(1, Item(2, "2-new"))

    println(list2)
}
```

By the way, it seems strange to keep a list of items where we identify them by their ids. Did you consider using a map instead?